# typescript: validate excess keys on value, returned from function

Tags: typescript

Let say I'm doing this:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type Rec = { [K in Keys]?: number }
let rec: Rec = { a: 1, d: 4 }
```

It results in:

```
Type '{ a: number; d: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Rec'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'd' does not exist in type 'Rec'
```

So it doesn't allow any extra keys on an object.

But if I do following:

```
type Func = () => Rec
const fn: Func = () => ({ a: 1, d: 4 })
```

TS is totally ok with it, despite given function definitely returns not a `Rec` type.

And, at the same time, using `const fn: Func = () => ({ a: false, d: 4 })` gives

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.(2322)
input.tsx(63, 12): The expected type comes from property 'a' which is declared here on type 'Rec'
```

So it actually does validate a returned value. But somehow doesn't care about excess keys.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90CNs80BjNAKFEigCUISUoBvKAbRigEsA7WeBALoB+AFxRuAVwC2+CACcoAX3IAbCMChz6Yug1QsMYgIwAaKABMxAFiXlK4aADEJ3PVAAUAShQA+WvXISAHtuBA0AM24xZ1dGL18PA2MzSygbRU9AkLCoAHcMYGiXN3jkP3ckqHCMFQQIFOslTyA)

Why this happens, and is there any way to don't allow extra keys on returned value in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `{a: 1, d: 4}` *is* of the `Rec` type.  Object types in TypeScript *generally* allow excess properties and are not "exact" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  There are good reasons for this having to do with subtyping and assignability.  For example:

```
class Foo {a: string = ""}
class Bar extends Foo {b: number = 123}
console.log(new Bar() instanceof Foo); // true
```

Note that every `Bar` is a `Foo`, which means that you can't say "all `Foo` objects *only* have an `a` property" without preventing class or interface inheritance and extension.  And since `interface` works the same way, and since TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not nominal, you don't even have to *declare* a `Bar` type for it to exist:

```
interface Foo2 {a: string};
// interface Bar2 extends Foo2 {b: number};
const bar2 = {a: "", b: 123 };
const foo2: Foo2 = bar2; // okay
```

So for better or worse we are stuck with a type system whereby extra properties do not break type compatibility.

---

Of course, this can be a source of errors.  So in the case where you are explicitly assigning a brand new object literal to a place that expects a particular object type, there are [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) that behave *as if* the type were exact.  These checks only happen in particular circumstances, as in your first example:

```
let rec: Rec = { a: 1, d: 4 }; // excess property warning
```

But return values from functions are not currently one of these circumstances.  The return value's type gets widened before any excess property checks can happen.   There is a quite old open GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241) which suggests that this should be changed so that return values from functions not be widened this way, and there's even an implementation of a potential fix at [microsoft/TypeScript#40311](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40311) but it was closed so it might never make it into the language.

---

There aren't any perfect ways to suppress excess properties in general.  My advice is to just accept that objects may have excess keys and ensure that any code you write would not break if this is the case.  You can do things which *discourage* excess properties, such as these:

```
// annotate return type explicitly
const fn2: Func = (): Rec => ({ a: 1, d: 4 }) // excess property warning

// use a generic type that gets mad about excess properties
const asFunc = <T extends Rec & Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof Rec>, never>>(
    cb: () => T
): Func => cb;
const fn3 = asFunc(() => ({ a: 1, d: 4 })); // error! number is not never
```

But they are more complicated and easily broken, since nothing whatsoever will stop you from doing this no matter how much you try to safeguard your `Func` type:

```
const someBadFunc = () => ({ a: 1, d: 4 });
const cannotPreventThis: Rec = someBadFunc();
```

---

Writing code that anticipates extra properties usually involves holding onto an array of known keys.  So don't do this:

```
function extraKeysBad(rec: Rec) {
    for (const k in rec) { 
        const v = rec[k as keyof Rec];  // bad assumption that k is keyof Rec 
        console.log(k + ": " + v?.toFixed(2))
    }
}

const extraKeys = {a: 1, b: 2, d: "four"};
extraKeysBad(extraKeys); // a: 1.00, b: 2.00, RUNTIME ERROR! v.toFixed not a function
```

Do this instead:

```
function extraKeysOkay(rec: Rec) {
    for (const k of ["a", "b", "c"] as const) {
        const v = rec[k];
        console.log(k + ": " + v?.toFixed(2))
    }
}

extraKeysOkay(extraKeys); // a: 1.00, b: 2.00, c: undefined
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90CNs80BjNAWAChRIoAlCElKAbygG0YoBLAO1ngIAugH4AXFF4BXALb4IAJygBfKgBsIwKAsYSGTVGwwSAjABooAEwkAWFQG4oAeidQIADxIQESMAoD2kAqgUADuGAq8fADmVFQ00ABiUrwGUAAUAJQoAHz0jFQk-rwIWgBmvBLJqcxZuRlGphbWUHbKmXGUJGoYPlCJ-v6sUMZQpQoxzABEUyqFPX0AQhFu7sAQvJZIA0Ns+BLScorMJgBMAMxzXcUI-hoAdGr+0em8EKFQywp1fKUYqRB-GV+oNMo4XFBgAopBBOnx1goyhgvCD-KdhqNxpNlPYqBD4YokSivuiPOtNttBuiWPtJLJ5AocYUblp8BF0YYRhIZhZaWdLkzriVylSqlTmGyFKdwa5-ABrDAgTp41z-Xj+YAYdbaTRSSKQ8DQDxgNTcEjcYBqJVC0pQCqnKopNJZPSMerpRpQcxWWwqbIQjxePp+QKKELhSIxToQqQIaAYKDRDaKM0G2jAAAWWsTmiQMgwlhG+H8Ui0ge8vgCQWA3G8zOFIwQ1TSAB4ACqrclbfJMABkPf8CksLYAop41FJLBAW3L4ECoG2LLOQPP9DkLG8AG6KHI5dJUKCHqAkWl1ZB5NtUTKOmrn4-4XE28q8S6oXrN9JnvIerle5q+9owWcVxFACBQAEI6SOJRuCQdUtC3RQD3rW1bhkCBlksZtamyO8f1Gb0WjaMEUK0Eg1Q1AAFHRt14YA2wzWDXTSNCMILD8SMoToyidGtik7BQMDgRBMPSHQSGY7IWAPI8ykHDIigbOUeH4cSpJko8j0U21N2YcT2GU3ooGXVdGCERwNM048bjuCBHmedJlIAaigKZuSgFzNxEe5gH8RJuHcCBLHSU5Mg6ShNNUSgoqoHjUj4-gyUE4SEAAeQVEAxN0Ht1Ii2T5PSbStGU+d2CmDApgsKZ8Eq1ySCmIRG2s4VcqsrSWSgXTUH0uVzMszTtNs+yXmc1z3M87zfP8wLgtC8LIqoGKnwEoTBGYFgCN5CRTn-Vy5L1KZBSS1bEHSxV0mOlKgIhAj7gABjuraoFOe7HuPCQUinMo+CCqhLsEUT-sQa7VVMV6npeh6LDoABVAA5NsAEkAFkRygEc6DoVK6EgzcfL8gKgskDURjtXjuGKIA)