# Typescript return type Object Literal ignores unknown properties

Tags: typescript, types, return-type, arrow-functions

I ran into an issue with typescript which I can't find an answer to and simply can't get my head around.

When defining a return type as `object` for an `arrow function`, I can add whatever property to the returned object without any errors occurring.

If I leave out properties or mistype a property (See examples below) TS correctly throws an error.

If I create the object and type them directly (not as return type in a function, but as simple `const`).

If anyone knows a workaround to define an EXACT `object` return type for an arrow function, I would much appreciate the help.

```
type TestType = {
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
}

// TS2741: Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ bar: string; }' but required in type 'TestType'.
const propMissing: TestType = {
    bar: 'asd',
};

// TS2322: Type '{ bar: string; foo: string; baz: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TestType'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'baz' does not exist in type 'TestType'.
const propAdded: TestType = {
    bar: 'asd',
    foo: 'ada',
    baz: 2,
};

// TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
const propType: TestType = {
    bar: 'asd',
    foo: 2,
};

// No errors
const allGood: TestType = {
    bar: 'asd',
    foo: 'asd',
};


// No errors. As expected because "propMissing" is declared as being TestType
const funcObjRefMissing: () => TestType = () => {
    return propMissing;
};

// No errors. As expected because "propAdded" is declared as being TestType
const funcObjRefAdded: () => TestType = () => ({
    ...propAdded,
});

// No error. Would expect same error as "propAdded": TS2322
const funcObjLiteral: () => TestType = () => ({
    foo: 'sf',
    bar: 'aasd',
    baz: 2
});

// TS2339: Property 'baz' does not exist on type 'TestType'.
funcObjLiteral().baz;

// Identical to above
const funcObjDestruct: () => TestType = () => {
    return {
        ...allGood,
        baz: 2
    };
}
funcObjDestruct().baz;


// TS2741: Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type 'TestType'.
const funcPropMissing: () => TestType = () => ({
    foo: 'sad',
});
```

### **To Conclude...**

I am looking for a compile error saying that I can not return an object containing `baz` as a property since 'baz' does not exist in type 'TestType`

### **Resolved**

Simply not possible currently, or maybe ever with TS due to well argued reasons.
For an in-depth response read **@jcalz** answer her https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266045/4211180

If you can and don't mind then be rewriting your arrow function to "normal" function, the return value is respected with excess property checking

```
// TS2322: Type '{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TestType'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'baz' does not exist in type 'TestType'.
function funcObjLiteral(): TestType {
    return {
        foo: 'sf',
        bar: 'aasd',
        baz: 2
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about _excess prop checking_? The caller of the function can only access the properties that are exposed via the `TestType` interface anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript: validate excess keys on value, returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263271/typescript-validate-excess-keys-on-value-returned-from-function)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately not. Even with `excess prop checking` I am missing an error.
What im looking for is a compile time error preventing me from in `funcObjLiteral` or `funcObjDestruct` to return an object containing the property `zoo` since that is not defined in `TestType`

Comment: That _is_ excess property checking. The point is that the excess props don't matter because they're not accessible anyway.

Comment: But even when the return type is made with excess prop checking I get no TS error for the return type. :/ unless I am misunderstanding this concept.
Heres my example without an error

`const funcObjLiteral: () => {[key in 'foo' | 'bar']: string;} = () => ({
 foo: 'sf',
 bar: 'aasd',
 baz: 2
});`

Comment: Alright I see. Excess prop checking is currently not possible as a return value from a function since a functions return value's type gets widened before any excess property checks can happen. 
Thank you @jonrsharpe for quick and accurate response!