# Restrict function return type properties when specifying function type in a function expression

Tags: typescript, function, types

I'm trying to create a generic type to define a common function shape (express handler). Here I've simplified this to get to the core of my issue:

So I've created a type to represent the common function shape:

```
type Builder = () => BuilderReturn;
type BuilderReturn = {
  prop1: string;
}
```

This means that a variable that is given this type must be assigned a function with no args that returns an object with one property, `prop1`, a `string`. However, when I use this function `type` in practice, while TypeScript *does* ensure prop1 is present and a string, it *doesn't* restrict the return type, meaning I can add arbitrary properties to the return object without TypeScript complaining:

```
const myBuilder: Builder = () => ({
  prop1: 'something',
  junk: true, // TypeScript doesn't care if this is here
});
```

My expectation would be that by specifying an object shape as a return type for the `Builder` type, this would ensure the return type matches the object shape, no exceptions.

Now, if I explicitly define the return type in my function definition (i.e., not relying on the return type checking implied in the `Builder` type), it does correctly flag `junk` as not being a member of `BuilderReturn`.

```
const myBuilder: Builder = (): BuilderReturn => ({
  prop1: 'something',
  junk: true, // TypeScript now identifies this as a problem
});
```

But this isn't ideal because I don't want consumers of this utility type to need to know that they have to specify both `Builder` *and* `BuilderReturn` each time a new builder function is defined.

Maybe I have an inherent misunderstanding about using a type defined as a function in a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) that expects very explicit inputs and outputs.

If anyone could cast some light on how to achieve this with a single type as a part of a function expression, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Excess properties are not really prohibited in TS and thus you should probably not write code that does bad things in the face of excess properties.  Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266045/2887218) to the linked question for more info.  You've got this tagged as "generics" but I don't see [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in this question so I've untagged that.  Let me know if I'm missing something about the question or issue.  Good luck!