# TypeScript type for "Object with key called ..."

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to make a function like

```js
function sortByKey<T>(items: T[], key: string): T[] {
  return items.sort((a, b) => a[key] - b[key]);
}
```

I need `T[key]` to be a `number`, but I'm not sure how to express that.

If I knew the key ahead of time I could obviously just do `{key: number}` but that doesn't work here.

I tried something like `sortByKey<K>(items: {[k: K]: number}[], key: K)` but that gives the error `"An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead."` I looked into mapped types but they don't seem to do what I need. Is something like this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: Why wouldn't `T extends { [x: string] : number }` not work for you? Generics can be a part of index signature only if the signature is a template literal, and even that is a very recent addition to the language

Comment: @OlegValter that works if the object has only fields that are numbers, right? but what if `T` is like `{i: number, name: string}`?

Comment: Well, why not use a union then? :) or combine known props and an index signature? The gist of the idea is to use an index signature as a constraint for the generic type parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the function to be generic both in `T`, the type of the `items` elements, and in `K`, the type of `key`.  You can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to be keylike (`K extends PropertyKey`) and constrain `T` to be a type with a `number` value at key `K` (`T extends Record<K, number>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)):

```
function sortByKey<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Record<K, number>>(
  items: T[], 
  key: K
): T[] {
  return items.sort((a, b) => a[key] - b[key]);
}
```

You can't write `{[k: K]: number}` because that's an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) which can't be generic.  But you can write `{[P in K]: number}` using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  Mapped types are similar to but distinct from index signatures; [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331699/2887218) for more information.  Anyway, `Record<K, number>` is an alias for `{[P in K]: number}`, so you were getting close.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygIQJ4GkCm2APLovgB5T5gAmyiACmnAA74Z6EA0iAKmZWp1EAJXwR0NEjzAgAtgCN2APmUAKGFTnIAXHwDaAXR4BrQntwBKPbyOIA3gFgAUIkRp8UEGiSb82gDpUDDU1AEMeBUtEAF5lRDD9M2xDRABaRAUkwkNLAG4XAF8gA)

Comment: Thanks, that works! I incorrectly assumed `T extends Record<K, number>` meant that `T` could **only** have keys of type `K` and they **all** had to be `number`s

Comment: A lot of people seem to think that TypeScript object types are "exact" or "sealed", but they're not.  If `A` and `B` are object types and `A extends B`, it means that `A` must have all the known keys from `B`, but it doesn't mean that `A` can't have more.  Indeed it would be a big problem if you couldn't add properties via extension like  `interface Foo extends Bar { baz: string }`.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266045/2887218) for more info