# Strict type check for object returned from a function

Tags: typescript

Could someone help me understand why the behaviors in the cases below are different?
Because I expected it should be the same, it should returns the error.
And can I declare type of a function with "strict" return object? (with the behavior of case 2)

```js
// OK
const check1: () => {foo: string} = () => ({foo: 'test', bar: 'test'})


// Type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'.
const check2 = (): {foo: string} => ({foo: 'test', bar: 'test'})
```

Comment: Search "typescript excess properties check arrow functions" See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266045/188031