# A type that does not allow exceeded properties in typescript function return object

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create a type that throws an error in the next case:

```
type Options = {
    optionA: string;
    optionB?: string;
} 

const myFun = ():Options => {
    const result = {optionA: 'hola', optionC: 'chao', optionB:'que tal'}
    return result; // no error, but I will like a type that catches it
}
```

So I want to create a type that allows typescript to catch exceeded properties (optionC) in an object when specifically set in the return type of the function.

The motivation is that, because optionB is optional, you can make a typo in the property name (optionBtypo) and then the return of the function will not catch it. This can produce bugs because you will expect optionB to be there but it is not.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
interface NoExceeded extends Options {
    [arg:string]: never
}
```

But I get `Property 'optionA' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'never'.`

I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined) without success.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: See the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263271/typescript-validate-excess-keys-on-value-returned-from-function) for various options; you could try to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRBdQw), but TS doesn't really want to prevent excess properties in general.

Comment: @jcalz Your example worked. Thank you for your support.