# Typescript generic: 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to build method generic in typescript and make it returns generic type but TS shows an error on it

```
export type DataGenerator<T> = <T>(props: {name: string}) => T;

const dataGenerator: DataGenerator<{city?: string}> = ({  name }) => {
    return {
        city: `${name}`
    }
}

dataGenerator({name: "xxx"})
```

error:

```
Type '<T>({ name }: { name: string; }) => { city: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DataGenerator<{ city?: string | undefined; }>'.
  Type '{ city: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ city: string; }'.
```

Any help?

Comment: Is this just a typo?  You’ve declared two type parameters of the same name; why?  Presumably you mean `type DataGenerator<T> =(props: {name: string}) => T;` but if so then there’s nothing wrong anymore

Comment: It's working with the solution but it doesn't show an error if returns a different object like add extra key with city

Comment: That's a followup question and out of scope for the question as asked... and most likely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64263271/2887218).  So what should we do here... close the question as cause by a typo?  Or should I write up an explanation for why you need to remove the second `<T>` for it to work?

Comment: ```export type DataGenerator<T> = (props: {name: string}) => T;

const dataGenerator: DataGenerator<{city?: string}> = ({  name })=> {
    return {
        city: "",
        postCode: "aaa",
    }
}

dataGenerator({name: "xxx"})
```

Comment: why accept "postCode" here? as you see the object should has city only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76000890/typescript-generic-for-method-it-allows-return-extra-data

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to respond without repeating almost the entirety of my last comment.  Please re-read it and answer the question in there, if you don't mind.

Comment: I didn't your comment, I see some people say we can't do validation by generic only. for the second <T> I removed to solve it `    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ city: string; }'.`

Comment: I'm not sure why we need to remove it, can you please explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different kinds of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in TypeScript.

---

On the one hand there are generic *types*, where the generic type parameter is declared on the name of the type:

```
type GenTypeAlias<T> = T | number;
interface GenInterface<T> { prop: T }
class GenClass<T> { prop: T[] = [] }
```

where in order to talk about a value of that type you need to specify the type *parameter* with a type *argument*:

```
type SpecificTypeAlias = GenTypeAlias<string>; // okay
interface SpecificInterface extends GenInterface<number> { }; // okay
class SpecificClass extends GenClass<boolean> { }; // okay
type Oops = GenTypeAlias; // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Generic type 'GenTypeAlias' requires 1 type argument.
```

For generic types, type arguments are specified by the person *supplying* the value of that type; if the type is a function, the *implementer* specifies the type argument.

---

On the other hand, there are generic *functions*, where the generic type parameter is declared on the call signature:

```
declare function genFunc<T>(val: T): T[];
type GenFunction = <T>(val: T) => T[];
```

where you can talk about a value of that type without specifying the type parameter; instead, you only specify the type parameter with a type argument when you *call* the function:

```
const genFunc2 = genFunc; // don't specify here
declare const alsoGenFunc: GenFunction; // don't specify here

const strArr = genFunc<string>("abc"); // specify here
// const strArr: string[]
const numArr = genFunc<number>(123); // specify here
// const numArr: number[]
```

Note that much of the time the compiler can *infer* the type argument for a generic function call, but it's still being specified at call time:

```
const boolArr = genFunc(true);
// function genFunc<boolean>(val: boolean): boolean[]
// const boolArr: boolean[]
```

For generic functions, type arguments are specified by the person *consuming* the value of that type; the *caller* specifies the type argument.

---

So let's look at your `DataGenerator` definition:

```
type DataGenerator<T> = <T>(props: { name: string }) => T;
// -------------> ^^^
// 'T' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Hmm, this seems to be *both* a generic function *and* a generic type, and furthermore the same type parameter name `T` is used for both of them.  Depending on your IDE you might see that the first `T` is grayed out, with a message that it has been declared but unused.  The inner `T` is [*shadowing* or *masking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking) the outer one, so the outer one is essentially ignored:

```
type DataGenerator<T> = <T>(props: { name: string }) => T;
//                 ^-  ^--------- refers to ----------^
```

Shadowing is confusing, so let's get rid of it by renaming the type parameters to be clear about what's happening:

```
type DataGenerator<T> = <U>(props: { name: string }) => U;
```

This is the same thing, but now you can plainly see what type is coming out.  As written, then, a `DataGenerator<T>` completely ignores `T` and resolves to a generic *function* which takes a value of type `{name: string}` and produces a value of type `U` *for any `U` the caller wants*.  That is very unlikely to be useful.

And it's not what you're supplying:

```
const dataGenerator: DataGenerator<{ city?: string }> = ({ name }) => { // error!
// -> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Type '{ city: string; }' is not assignable to type 'U'.
  return { city: `${name}` }
}
```

Indeed, you are returning `{ city: string }`, which cannot be guaranteed to be the same as the `U` type the caller will specify.

---

You don't want this; you don't want the caller to choose the type argument at all.

Presumably what you want is for a `DataGenerator<T>` to be a non-generic function that takes a value of type `{name: string}` and produces a value of type `T`.  The *implementer* will choose `T`, not the *caller*.  And that means the innermost type parameter should be removed:

```
type DataGenerator<T> = (props: { name: string }) => T;
```

And once we do that, everything works:

```
const dataGenerator: DataGenerator<{ city?: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  return { city: `${name}` }
} // okay

const result = dataGenerator({ name: "xxx" });
// const result: { city?: string }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2AVcECCAbAlgQwM4B5EA+KAXikSgB8p4BXAWwCMIAnAbgChN5g2AzbAGNoceAEleA4REIkA3lDCsA9mABcFKAF9OQ9HlywEAYQO4CxKIuVrNiANoBdMlGc7OnUJCgBlSEKY-JhCyJAYOEbkYmFoWHj4uMCsPADmROxQAPRZUCoA1tgg3FKsgiJ+AUEhknxlMlAQAB588AAmRmK10iL49MxsCjqZOXmFxfqGlRCBwUJmU82tHcbwCxb4TCoq6BDY8EPaI7kFRV4oUADyalGrsRF4x42sqqwAhJyjALQ-v18kAD8gcCQUDPrkxGwQlBvNAAOQxFAPXBwqCsCAARzomHRRgAjDCLthWKlGAhgAA6TycNozAzoqD8OjwITATAqeBQVIIABizKEcgAFAA3bDoewASnszi4sNWfJZbI5riFovFFAlZBIjicXD0HKSXN5-IATK5ufAFUIuLTJgyhAbgFAxbgVGIrZp3fylfA9Q74IakqxUC9zcaWYlkmkiIKAETYJhCWMSrijf2B5Ih1iaINpZz6gNO-pZsOW-l9RgsVgxvEmgDMKfBUHTRcYWc0-Sr+YLhq2OxL5AtVsFyToEEboyZivZnKH5b7u32MbVmgXe3gUqga-2+bTjq323Q7YPO3X3fg2AYEFwYAaADk1NB5J4oISfAARbDAbCQ1hflSsHIKoAKoxrYYC4JoigXleOZRvAqQ6JqpAkMBXCvt8fxYb8JAAHr4ZwGG5HCiCopgRi2vSEBtFudBOpgwBGGqY5QORtAQMKbBonsbRUi+zb7m0X4-ggbD-tmUCft+v7ifgiiBKAAD8cEpAhOgkOQgrQZe0DaMhQyjGwrwfERUD-FAoKWWCpmvrEUBwvJDEgCpaSZNoZFGPAKhOoYmCpBeTC7DCKhvvCwFwlSr6vuiwB0KwnKOaAmgAAYACTyDBEDaMlHivrohFQEJ0miX+wAAVptA6ZosZNLVsZIZw+WZTeDQAJoQGA1gFXKUkifAYllYBViaeBkHWJVsFQLmal6VqFB6q+LaFcJMmDZovWrQBcnNk5ylTfBiHaBpUAVZlSFzc+UXcbF8XjQpzlQGlGU6dluU6NkJzjPxS24nQ6BOuQRV9QN5XaZNNV1Uh6EfQJhbcbgf3AFBO1KS5M2eNoQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's helpful. but Can you see the link "Playground link to code" I added 2 methods lines 47 and 52, In the first one, we can return "postalCode" but postalCode isn't existed to interface with the city. line 52, it shows warning

Comment:  I can't see things you do in your own web browser, no. But I strongly suspect that you are yet again asking about something out of scope for this question.  Presumably it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64263271/2887218), right?  Have you looked at that?  Either way, could we please stop talking about that here, where it's not appropriate?

Comment: it's fine, Thanks