Why does the TypeScript map function need a return type annotation to behave as expected, and what can I do about it?
Background
I want to map a list of items and change 1 attribute of each item. However, if I make a typo in the attribute name, TypeScript might not catch it.
Explanation
Define a type (Dog).
type Dog = { breed: string; name: string; };

Create a list of dogs.
const dogs: Dog[] = [];

Now map the dog list, but change the breed of every dog. I made a typo in assigning the breed field, but TS doesn't say anything. That's bad because

A) I failed to actually change the thing I wanted to change, and
B) the type of newDogs1 isn't actually Dog[], even though TS thinks it is.

const newDogs1: Dog[] = dogs.map((dog) => {
    return {
        ...dog,
        breeeeeeeeeeeed: 'typo!', // no error :(
    };
});

If I write the function like this, TS warns me. The problem is this is not a natrual way to write the code.
const newDogs2: Dog[] = dogs.map((dog) => {
    const result: Dog = {
        ...dog,
        breeeeeeeeeeeed: 'typo!', // error :)
    };
    return result;
});

Adding a type parameter to the map function does not solve the issue. Why not? The type of the function passed into map is (value: Dog, index: number, array: Dog[]) => Dog, which has the return type Dog. Shouldn't that mean that the function has to return an object of type Dog? Currently it's returning an object of type Dog & {/*something*/}, which is assignable to Dog but isn't Dog. But take a look at newDogs2. I assigned an object of type Dog & {/*something*/} to Dog, and it resulted in an error. So why does newDogs3 not have that same error?
const newDogs3: Dog[] = dogs.map<Dog>((dog) => {
    return {
        ...dog,
        breeeeeeeeeeeed: 'typo!', // no error :(
    };
});

Adding the return type annotation to the map argument function makes TS understand the problem.
const newDogs4: Dog[] = dogs.map((dog): Dog => {
    return {
        ...dog,
        breeeeeeeeeeeed: 'typo!', // error :)
    };
});

For newDogs3 and newDogs4, the type of the map function is the same: Array<Dog>.map<Dog>(callbackfn: (value: Dog, index: number, array: Dog[]) => Dog, thisArg?: any): Dog[]
Question

Why does giving <Dog> to map (see newDogs3) result in no error, while giving : Dog to the argument of map (see newDogs4) results in an error?
What can I do to avoid this pitfall? The newDogs1 pattern is fairly common. Is there a TS setting or maybe an eslint rule I can use to help avoid this?

Playground link

You may be interested in this

SO question posts should ask a single primary question and not multiple. Which of your two questions is the one that needs to be answered here?

This isn't specific to map(), but to any callback function, or to any function for that matter. -- My plan is to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263271/typescript-validate-excess-keys-on-value-returned-from-function unless I see something here that clearly distinguishes it.

Yes, it is a duplicate of that question, which is also asking for the same 2 critical points: "why does this happen and how can I prevent it?" The Stricter object literal assignment checks section from the TS docs is the "why?", and the second half of that question's accepted answer is the "what can I do?" I voted to close the question as a duplicate.
